# OpenGL: Multiple Overlapping Viewports Flickering

Tags: c++, opengl, viewport

I am trying to create two viewports in my window: a main, full screen view and a smaller view in the upper left corner. I've looked the issue up and looked at the solutions: I am using glScissor() and glViewport(), clearing my depth buffer bit, enabling my depth buffer bit, and rendering only once (after a for loop). But clearly, I am missing something. Here is my code. Thank you in advance.

Edit: 
link to screenshots: http://imgur[dot]com/a/sdoUy
Basically, the upper left mini viewport flickers, disappearing and reappearing very quickly.

```
void viewports() {
float width = wWidth;
float height = wHeight; 

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    glClearColor(.392,.584,.929,0.0f);

    if (i == 0) {
        //main view
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
        glViewport(0,0,(GLsizei)width,(GLsizei)height);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluPerspective(60,(GLfloat)width/(GLfloat)height,1.0,100.0);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        keyOp();
        camera();
    } else if (i == 1) {
        glScissor(0,height - height/3,(GLsizei)height/3,(GLsizei)height/3);
        glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
        glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glViewport(0,height - height/3,(GLsizei)height/3,(GLsizei)height/3);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluPerspective(60,1,1.0,100.0);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluLookAt(0,40,-15,0,-1,-15,1,0,0);
        glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
    }
    renderScene();
}
}
```

Comment: Can you give a better description of what the problem is?

Comment: Do you have double buffering enabled? It should be something you request when you create the context.

Comment: Yes, in my main() I have:
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
and I call glutSwapBuffers(); at the end of my renderScene() function. I can post more code if it helps.

Comment: Reducing the number of times glutSwapBuffers is called seems to be a common solution, but I am already calling it only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call glutSwapBuffers in renderscene. You call renderscene twice per frame (for i==0 and i==1), so you're drawing main screen, swap, draw minimap, swap, repeat.

You need to draw both main and minimap, and then swap.

Also don't bother calling glClearColor so many times, you only need to call it once at init.

Comment: Aha you are correct! I guess I'd found the answer several times online and thought I had already fixed it, but I was indeed calling swapBuffers more than once. I moved my swapBuffers to just after the "for" loop, and now that I'm REALLY only calling it once the flickering has stopped. I also moved my ClearColor to the init() section. Thank you! I'm both happy and embarrassed at such a silly mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will help with your flickering problem but I notice you have written:

```
glClearColor(.392,.584,929,0.0f);
```

With the third parameter being 929 instead of what I assume you wanted, .929

Comment: Thanks for the sharp eye! Changed the parameter but it had no effect on the flicker.